# How to implement ng-bootstrap table sort, search-filter and pagination using data from API

Tags: angular, ng-bootstrap, bootstrap-table

I'm implementing a transaction table filled with data from an API that I created myself, I want to make it sortable, filterable and pagination. I'm trying to do it with ng-bootstrap, I saw the documentation, but I just simply can't get it working, in the complete example they use a static data array.

I tried to adapt what I saw in the documentation page: 
https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/table/examples#sortable
but I couldn't get it to work.

// TS

```js
    import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
    import { NgxSpinnerService } from 'ngx-spinner';

    import { TransactionsService } from '../transactions.service';
    import { Transactions, Career, Faculty, RoleType } from 'src/assets/models';
    import { RegisterService } from '../register.service';
    import { AlertService } from '../alert.service';

    @Component({
      selector: 'app-admin',
      templateUrl: './admin.component.html',
      styleUrls: ['./admin.component.scss']
    })
    export class AdminComponent implements OnInit {

      content: Transactions;

      analytic = false;
      uniFaculties: Faculty;
      uniCareers: Career;
      uniUsers: RoleType;

      constructor(
        private modalService: NgbModal,
        private spinner: NgxSpinnerService,
        private alertService: AlertService,
        private transactionService: TransactionsService
      ) { }

      ngOnInit() {
        this.spinner.show();
        this.transactionService.getAllTransactions()
          .subscribe(res => {
            this.content = res;
            console.log(this.content); // testing all transaction object

          });
        this.spinner.hide();
      }
    }
```

// HTML

```html
    <div class="fluid-container admin-transactions" *ngIf="content">
      <h1><span class="badge badge-info header-transactions"><i class="fas fa-exchange-alt"></i> Transacciones</span></h1>
      <table class="table table-hover fixed_header">
        <thead class="thead table-info">
          <tr class="row table-info">
            <th class="col-1 d-flex justify-content-center" scope="col">ID de Transacción</th>
            <th class="col-1 d-flex justify-content-center" scope="col">ID de Usuario</th>
            <th class="col-1 d-flex justify-content-center" scope="col">Tipo</th>
            <th class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center" scope="col">Fecha</th>
            <th class="col-3 d-flex justify-content-center" scope="col">Descripción</th>
            <th class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-center" scope="col">Monto</th>
          </tr>
        </thead>
        <tbody>
          <tr class="row" *ngFor='let row of content.transactions'>
            <td class="col-1 d-flex justify-content-center id">{{ row.trx_ID }}</td>
            <td class="col-1 d-flex justify-content-center id">{{ row.user_ID }}</td>
            <td class="col-1 d-flex justify-content-center trx" [ngClass]="{'custom-class': row.trx_type === 'RCH' && row.amount !== 0, 'default-color': row.trx_type !== 'RCH'}">{{ row.trx_type}}</td>
            <td class="col-4 d-flex justify-content-center date">{{ row.date | date:'long' }} </td>
            <td class="col-3 d-flex justify-content-center description">{{ row.description }}</td>
            <td class="col-2 d-flex justify-content-center amount" [ngClass]="{'rch-class': row.trx_type === 'RCH' && row.amount !== 0 , 'pay-class': row.trx_type !== 'RCH'}">{{ row.amount | currency }}</td>
          </tr>
        </tbody>
      </table>
    </div>
    <hr>
```

Comment: the code is currently working properly, but without any of the features I want (sort, search, filter, pagination).